# Store device tokens for push notification in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I will send push notification via gcm in ejabberd.If user is offline I will write a module for offline message hook and I will send push notification to receiver.But I need device token for send request to gcm servers.I don't know how to store device token in ejabberd ? I need help.How can I store device tokens for each user in ejabberd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is "how do I store data in Erlang?"

There are many answers. Probably, you want to read about [Mnesia](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/mnesia). Or [use a relational database](https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql). Or use basically any other data store (Redis, MongoDB, DynamoDB, etc, etc, etc) depending on your needs and situation.